# How to restrict a child type in parent type?

Tags: c++

I have a class type like this:

```
struct permanent_runnable {
    static std::vector<permanent_runnable*> instants;
protected:
    permanent_runnable() {
        instants.push_back(this);
    }
public:
    virtual ~permanent_runnable() {}
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop() = 0;
};
```

I hope that all types inherited from this permanent_runnable type have no copy constructors and no assignable operators.If someone did not follow the rule, a compile error would output!

What can I do to archive that?

Comment: Do you mean [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)? If you allow subclassing you can't necessarily dictate terms on what, if any constructors they create.

Comment: @tadman `final` can only be for `virtual` functions ... and a copy constructor cannot be `virtual`.

Comment: @AdrianMole When used on a class or struct it means you can't subclass. When used on a function it means that.

Comment: @tadman Then there would be no case of the OP's *"...all types inherited from this..."*.

Comment: If you really want to lock this down, it might be better to make this class `final` and instead have some other mechanism for adding that functionality as user extensions. There's surely a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) you can use for inspiration as to how to do that.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's what I'm saying. Either you allow subclassing and have to deal with the uncertainty of what they might do to your class, or you don't.

Comment: Will **your code** work incorrectly if someone creates a derived class that has a copy constructor? If not, you're looking to give **advice**, not requirements. Are you absolutely certain that there is no conceivable circumstance where making a derived class copyable is appropriate?

Comment: I hope subclass is singleton through the restriction of super class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent a user to do something undesired. They will find a way if they try hard enough. Having said this,  making the base non-assignable and non-copy constructible is a good indication that derived classes should also not provide those:

```
struct base {
    base() = default;
    base& operator=(const base&) = delete;
    base(const base&) = delete;
};

struct derived : base {};

int main()
{
    derived a;
    //derived b(a);  // error
    derived c;
    //c = a; // error
}
```

I suppose you actually want `permanent_runnable` to be non-assignable and non-copy constructible, because requiring that of derived classes while the class itself can be copy constructed and assigned isn't sound.

Answer (score 1):

All you can reasonably do is to delete the copy constructor and copy assignment. The derived types can have those operators but they won’t be able to copy the base class’s object. They’d need to create a whole new instance instead. So that achieves what you wish, and there’s really nothing to worry about with regards to derived types. The base class will prevent copying by mistake and give a clear sign of intent as to its use.

Anyone wanting to make a copy can of course make a copy — undefined behavior doesn’t mean that if you get down to machine level you can’t do anything you want. I mean: if I really wanted to make a copy of that object I would peruse the ABI spec for the architecture you’re on and make the copy using low level primitives. You can’t really prevent that if there’s no code review culture in place, but that’s not something you should worry about anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I implemented it like this:

```
#include <vector>

template<class Type>
struct container
{
    static std::vector<Type*> instants;
};
struct controller {
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop() = 0;
    virtual ~controller() {}
};
template<class Type>
std::vector<Type*> container<Type>::instants;

template<class Type>
struct permanent_runnable :public controller {
protected:
    permanent_runnable() { container<controller>::instants.push_back(this); }
    permanent_runnable(const permanent_runnable&) = delete;
    permanent_runnable& operator=(const permanent_runnable&) = delete;
public:
    virtual ~permanent_runnable() {}

    static Type& instance() {
        return ins;
    }
private:
    static Type ins;
};
template<class Type>
Type permanent_runnable<Type>::ins;

struct A :public permanent_runnable<A> {
    virtual void start() {
        std::cout << "A::start" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void stop() {
        std::cout << "A::stop" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A(){
        std::cout << "!~A" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct B :public permanent_runnable<B> {
    virtual void start() {
        std::cout << "B::start" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void stop() {
        std::cout << "B::stop" << std::endl;
    }
    ~B() {
        std::cout << "!~B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A::instance();
    A::instance();//for check
    B::instance();
    B::instance();//for check
    
    for (auto ins : container<controller>::instants) {
        ins->start();
        ins->stop();
        ins->~controller();
    }
    auto size = container<controller>::instants.size();
    container<controller>::instants.clear();
     size = container<controller>::instants.size();
    return 0;
}
```